# Entire, non-constant function $f$ such that the zeros of $f$ are $Z(f)= \varnothing$ and $|Z(f)|= \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis

Give an example of a function $f$ which is entire, non-constant and not identically zero and such that the zeros of $f$ are
$1)\ |Z(f)|=0$ and  $2)\ |Z(f)|= \infty$.
I thought that maybe we consider
$f(z)= e^{z}$ and $f(z)= \sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{k}$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k$ is not entire.

Comment: why? Every entire function f(z) can be represented as a power series

Comment: What you say is true, as a consequence of the fact that a function is entire if and  only if it is the limit of a power series that converges on $\Bbb C$. Obviously the unspoken implication you make is false.

Comment: @KhalidKabouri But not every power series is an entire function; here: $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^\infty z^k = \frac{1}{1-z}$ is not defined at $z=1$.

Comment: When you write $Z(f)=\infty$, do you mean that the set of zeros of $f$ has infinite cardinality or that the set of zeros of $f$ consists of the point $\infty$? In the first case you can take $f(z)=\sin(z)$, which has all the points $\pi n,\ n\in\mathbb{Z}$ as zeros. In the latter case, there is no such function, since $f$ would be entire and bounded, and therefore constant.

Comment: Yes I meant that the set of zeros of f has infinite cardinality